# Celery - задачи выполнены, но результатов нет

Tags: python, celery

Имеется странный кейс с Celery.
ОС - Убунту, 8 ядер, Redis.
Таска выполняет запрос к БД, и складывает данные в файлы на харде (по файлу на задачу). Отправляю 10 задач в очередь - в flower отмечены все 10 - успешно выполнены. Однако, результатов (файлов) создается только 8 (если указать -с 7 - то будет создано только 7). Ошибок от Celery нет.

Не понимаю, почему не сохраняются остальные результаты? В какую сторону стоит капать?

main.py

```py
....
    date_from = date(args.year_from, args.month_from, 1)
    date_to = date(args.year_to, args.month_to, calendar.monthrange(args.year_to, args.month_to)[1])
    result_folder_name = 'celery_report_{0}'.format(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    result_folder_path = '{0}/{1}'.format(os.getcwd(), result_folder_name)
    os.mkdir(result_folder_path)
    with open(args.ids_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as name_file:
        for name_str in name_file.readlines():
            for start_dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=date_from, until=date_to):
                end_dt = date(start_dt.year, start_dt.month, calendar.monthrange(start_dt.year, start_dt.month)[1])
                start_dt = start_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                end_dt = end_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                report_date = start_dt.split('-')
                r_id = name_str.strip('\n\t').strip(' ')
                get_stat.delay(r_id, start_dt, end_dt, report_date, result_folder_path)
        print('All tasks send!')
```

tasks.py

````py
@app.task(acks_late=True)
def get_stat(rid, start_dt, end_dt, report_date, result_folder_path):
    writer = CsvReporter('{0}/csv_report_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}.csv'.format(result_folder_path, rid, start_dt,nd_dt, uuid.uuid4().hex))
    writer.create_file()
    ch_sum_result, = get_data_from_ch(rid, start_dt, end_dt)
    web_sum_result = get_data_from_webpage(start_dt, end_dt, rid)
    writer.write_summary_data_to_file(rid, ch_sum_result, web_sum_result, report_date)```
````

Comment: Покажите код. Вдруг несколько задач пишут в один и тот же файл, например

Comment: Нет, не в один, конечно же. Эту мысль сразу проверил.

Comment: Возможно плохо проверили, покажите код

Comment: Хорошо. Добавил в пост.

Comment: Что такое `CsvReporter`?

Comment: похоже что это pytest , но лучшебы импорты тоже увидеть

Comment: CsvReporter просто небольшой класс, который отвечает за создание файла и за запись в файл заголовков/данных. pytest здесь не при чем

Comment: В логах celery есть записи типа `Received task: get_stat` и `Task get_stat[b3e5538c-b6f9-4820-9fc9-b329ffa3205b] succeeded in 0.0737533138599s`?

Comment: Да, есть. Решение нашлось. Правда, так и понял с чего такое поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внезапно, решилось добавлением --max-memory-per-child=10000 (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/cli.html) при запуске Celery.

Comment: Вы таким образом просто спровоцировали перезапуск воркеров после каждой задачи и замаскировали проблему, а не решили её. Зря вы так и не показали весь код.

Comment: Как скажете, что из кода еще может быть необходимо?

Comment: Хотя бы CsvReporter для начала